# using ios 5.0.1 with xcode 4.1

Tags: xcode

is any chance to run ios 5.0.1 device with xcode 4.1  ?

because i am using cocos2d and with xcode 4.2 i have some strange errors with no success of repairing

i was trying this link

http://aussiebloke.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-your-ios-5-device-with-xcode-41.html

but it stuck on "fetching debug symbols..." when i did it and running xcode 4.1 with iphone 5.0.1 joined to computer Macbook